# Apache Ignite nodes cannot communicate

Tags: ignite

I've configured Apache Ignite 1.8.0 programmatically and can start a server with a single node, but when another node joins, they cannot communicate and I receive many of the following two messages in the logs. These continue until the other node is stopped.

```
ERROR 12:52:39,187-0800 [*Initialization*] util.nio.GridDirectParser: Failed to read message [msg=null, buf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=5 lim=420 cap=32768], reader=null, ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [selectorIdx=0, queueSize=1, writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=5 lim=420 cap=32768], recovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/10.97.184.106:5702, rmtAddr=/10.97.189.92:58788, createTime=1484945559174, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=420, sndSchedTime=1484945559174, lastSndTime=1484945559174, lastRcvTime=1484945559185, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@21e93eaf, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Invalid message type: -84
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoMessageFactory.create(GridIoMessageFactory.java:805)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$5.create(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1631)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser.decode(GridDirectParser.java:76)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.onMessageReceived(GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:2332)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:918)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:1583)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1289)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
WARN 12:52:39,188-0800 [*Initialization*] communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi: Failed to process selector key (will close): GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [selectorIdx=0, queueSize=1, writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=5 lim=420 cap=32768], recovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/10.97.184.106:5702, rmtAddr=/10.97.189.92:58788, createTime=1484945559174, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=420, sndSchedTime=1484945559174, lastSndTime=1484945559174, lastRcvTime=1484945559185, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@21e93eaf, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true]]
ERROR 12:52:39,189-0800 [*Initialization*] communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi: Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception.
class org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioException: Invalid message type: -84
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:1595)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1289)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Invalid message type: -84
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoMessageFactory.create(GridIoMessageFactory.java:805)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$5.create(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1631)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser.decode(GridDirectParser.java:76)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.onMessageReceived(GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:107)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:2332)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:918)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:1583)
    ... 4 more
```

Version information.

```
>>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 1.8.0#20161205-sha1:9ca40dbeb7d559fcb299bdb6f5c90cdf8ce7e533
>>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> OS name: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
>>> CPU(s): 2
>>> Heap: 3.6GB
>>> VM name: 13752@host
>>> Grid name: T-XXX
>>> Local node [ID=983EC5A0-2D9A-40C9-B4C3-3D59739BDDB9, order=1, clientMode=false]
>>> Local node addresses: [hostname.example.com/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /10.97.184.106, /127.0.0.1]
>>> Local ports: TCP:5702 TCP:5703 TCP:5705
```

One of the similar issues I've found in my research is that it is recommended to disable the shared memory feature (setSharedMemoryPort -1) as a first step in removing a problem like this.

The server is running on Windows and the other server joining the cache is on OSX.

```
INFO 12:50:17,569-0800 [*Initialization*] ignite.internal.IgniteKernal%T-XXX: OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
```

How do I prevent these errors? Have I configured the cluster poorly or is there an incompatibility between the two machines I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely it's a misconfiguration issue. This can happen if discovery SPI on one node tries to connect to communication SPI on another node. See this post: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Invalid-message-type-84-error-td9869.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Yes, an inspection of the configuration settings was warranted!

Comment: @Valentin I am having issues connecting to ignite from my local PC I have a running ignite cluster in AWS I am trying to connect from my local machiene